# Every attempt at insert fails

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me why none of these inserts work?

```
insert into users password values ("e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e") where ID = 36;
```

---

```
insert into users (password) values ("e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e") where ID = 36;
```

---

```
insert into users ("password") values ("e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e") where ID = 36;
```

Comment: it seems you are trying to update an existing record but using insert query. If you use just insert into users ("password") values ("e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e"); it will work

Comment: That won't work.  Username, host are both mandatory.  He needs to do an update.  I wouldn't do this anyway.  I would get the user, host etc and then change password, not update or insert.

Comment: Xyz perhaps [reading the MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) will help you solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You need an update.

```
 Update users set password="something" where Id=36
```

Would be the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can't do INSERT with WHERE clause

Maybe you needed to do UPDATE

```
UPDATE users SET password ='e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e' WHERE ID=36;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query seems to be wrong. You are using Insert into and at the last you are using Where clause.